# Best dynamic array allocation technique for array rotation program

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

I have made an array rotation program that will allow the user to enter nine numbers (nine just to test that it works). The nine numbers will be stored into an array and rotated in a rotateArray() function. I'm trying to make it so that the user can be able to enter as many numbers as they want. Would the arraylist be the best way to dynamically allocate the array capacity?

```
    int[] userArray = new int[9];

System.out.println("This program can also rotate arrays.\n" +
                "Enter 9 single digit integers separated by spaces");
for(int i = 0; i<userArray.length; i++)
{
    userArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("The array you entered is: " + Arrays.toString(userArray) +"\n"+
                   "When your array is rotated, it looks like this: \n" + 
                   Arrays.toString(rotateArray(userArray)));
```

}

Comment: "Would the arraylist be the best way to dynamically allocate the array capacity?" Yes. Also, it is unclear what you mean by "rotate"

Comment: if i entered "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" the program will return "9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1". Sorry i made it unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the arraylist be the best way to dynamically allocate the array capacity?

Yes, you can use Arraylists. But the best way? Saying "yes" would be a daring answer, but clearly it's better to use in this case.

In given scenerio, it can be used like this:

```
    //an arraylist

    ArrayList<Integer> userArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("This program can also rotate arrays.\n" + "Enter any numbers, type 'end' when you finish");

    //flag for while loop, in case the user prompts "end"

    boolean endNotPrompted = true;

    //scanner
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(endNotPrompted) {

        //if user input is a number
        if(scan.hasNextInt() == true) {
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            userArrayList .add(num);
        }

        //if not a number, checks if the user wants to finish entering numbers
        else if(scan.nextLine().equals("end")) {
            endNotPrompted = false;

        }
    }

    scan.close();


    /*
     *rest of your code
     */
```

When using an ArrayList, you need not to know the exact size of the user input.